# Other countries or religion in dwapuryug?

Tags: other-religions

im very confused since many days as i heard about some sumerian kings list which states their kings in order and says that the kings before flood lived even upto 36000 years and after flood kings started with having age as long as 900 .. how is it possible as i have always heard that no other religion except sanatan(jainism also) or country was there until kalyug. I have researched a little. It says that kings are not in chronological order but still how is it possible? Are they lying? Can someone give proofs from scriptures or guru lectures that their was no other country or religion except vedic dharma. Thank you.